# input for Alternating Least Square

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collaborative-filtering

We are using ALS for a recommender model based on user/click data via Spark/Scala.

The rating column is a score [0,1]

```
val als = new ALS()
    .setImplicitPrefs(true)
    .setRank(myrank)
    .setRegParam(mylambda)
    .setAlpha(myalpha)
    .setMaxIter(numIter)
    .setUserCol("myuseridx")
    .setItemCol("myitemidx")
    .setRatingCol("rating")
val model = als.fit(training)
```

My question is: must the input data for implicit models technically contain all user item combinations, i.e. also the ones which were not bought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALS solves the recommender problem by fixing the user or the item matrix and solving it using least squares. Essentially, for an implicit dataset, it means that all items that are not set to one considered zeros. So you'd only need to include the positive observations.

Some more discussion here:
http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf

Comment: "Unlike explicit datasets, here the model should take all user-item preferences as an input, including those which are not related to any input observation (thus hinting to a zero preference). This is crucial, as the given observations are inherently biased towards a positive preference, and thus do not reflect well the user profile. 
However, taking all user-item values as an input to the model raises serious scalability issues "

Comment: Yes, that's correct. As I mentioned even if you don't set the zeros explicitly the model would consider them as zeros.

Comment: This quote is coming from : http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf

but now that I remember what is the purpose of the hyperparameter alpha. I think you are right. But now I have another question if you don't mind helping me. How can I compute the AUC score of my model ? 

I have the ratings label of my training set and if I follow the logic of not placing the zero value inside of my RDD[Ratings] i have trouble to understand how can I calculate my TP - FP - TN - FN score. 

thank you

Comment: I just meant that it's not necessary to put in the zeros, as the model would consider them (it'd store in a sparse vector which is more efficient to score and use). but for evaluation, you'd assume that the zeros are there (ie items that the user didn't buy means that the user didn't like).